# Is “ill at ease” perfectly interchangeable with “uncomfortable”?

Tags: meaning, idioms

There was the following sentence in a series about the art and craft of writing in *New York Times* (April 29) written by Tim Kreider under the title, “[The Power of ‘I Don’t Know’](http://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2013/04/29/the-power-of-i-dont-know/?hp)”:

> I’m always *ill at ease* when I find myself conscripted by the media into the role of Expert on some subject about which I have rashly written. I felt like the explanatory caption beneath my name on-screen ought to be: PERSON IN WORLD. [*emphasis added*]

As I checked a dictionary (OALED) at hand, it defines *ill at ease* as an idiom to mean
uncomfortable and embarrassed, and *uncomfortable* as:

> 3. anxious, embarrassed or afraid and unable to relax
>   4. unpleasant or difficult to deal with

Are they saying the same thing? Does *ill at ease* sound more familiar and at-home than *uncomfortable*, or are they perfectly interchangeable?

Comment: Comparing the tone of "uncomfortable" to the tone of "ill at ease" invites subjective judgment, but in my view "ill at ease" is by no means less formal or more familiar than "uncomfortable." I think that they are extremely similar in tone, and that neither is at all informal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. No word or phrase is **100%** subsitutable for any other word or phrase.

For instance, *uncomfortable* can take a *that*-complement

- *He's uncomfortable that she's jealous of him.*

whereas *ill at ease* is less adaptable

- **He's ill at ease that she's jealous of him.*

This is pretty much normal behavior for phrases; they aren't as old as words, and they don't have as many affordances and idioms.

As far as semantics is concerned, they mean more or less the same thing;
**but**, if one looks at the original sense, *ill at ease* means 'permanently uncomfortable'; i.e, 'uncomfortable while relaxing'. This is a significant extension of simply *uncomfortable*.

Comment: Well. That's why the author said I'm "always" ill at ease when ....

Comment: Let me add to this that "uncomfortable" can describe physical as well as emotional discomfort, but "ill at ease" describes only emotional discomfort. One doesn't say "I feel **ill at ease** in these shoes because they're too tight"; one says "I feel **uncomfortable** in these shoes because they're too tight". Or one says "These shoes are **uncomfortable**", not "These shoes are **ill at ease**". Ergo, they are not "perfectly interchangeable". _Gnu_ & _wildebeest_ are at least 99% interchangeable: same animal but different names from different languages.